Android to Electronjs communication
I'm new to both Kotlin and Electronjs, I want to allow my users to control certain features in the desktop app from their phones so I was thinking about how would i go about communication, I'm expecting both devices to be on the same LAN

Bluetooth.- I've seen how to implement this and seems pretty straight forward
Rest API/Sockets.- I would like to offer these options in case the desktop device does not have bluetooth. Is this doable in electronjs?

Thanks!
